AIError: failed to build tensor image: Tensor error: Unknown internal error: failed to decode u8
I am trying to use the cloudflare workers model, specifically the “llama-3.2-11b-vision-instruct”, but I am getting the following error:
AiError: AiError: AiError: Tensor error: failed to build tensor image: Tensor error: Unknown internal error: failed to decode u8”, ‘code’:3016
is the function where I try to make a request to the CloudFlare service to use the model and from there validate that it complies with what is required or can describe to me what is in the image.
I want to know why I get this error and how to fix it?

I encountered the same error and fixed it. You can try with my example below. It works without using base64:
import requests
import base64
import os
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image

# Your Cloudflare credentials
account_id = ""
auth_token = ""

# The URL of your image
image_url = ""

# Download and process image
response = requests.get(image_url)
image_bytes = response.content

image_array = list(bytes(image_bytes))

# Create payload
payload = {
    "prompt": "What's in this image?",
    "image": image_array
}

# Make request
response = requests.post(
f"https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/accounts/{account_id}/ai/run/@cf/meta/llama-3.2-11b-vision-instruct",
    headers={"Authorization": f"Bearer {auth_token}"},
    json=payload
)

print(f"Status Code: {response.status_code}")
print(f"Response: {response.json()}")

This fixed the issue for me. Let me know if it works for you!
